# How to check if database entry is corrupt with entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I am using a sqlite database. Within this database i have a table which contains a field named CREATED_ON of type TEXT to store the creation timestamp.
In my C# code the field is of type DATETIME.

If i try to get all entries via the DBSET normally everything works fine

```
return context.dbset.ToList();
```

Unfortunately there is a problem in my code that sometimes a corrupt value (string not parasable to DATETIME) is stored in the CREATED_ON field (At the moment i do not know why this happens). If i try to get all entries i get following error message:

> "The 'Created_On' property on 'FileInfos' could not be set to a 'System.String' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.DateTime'. "

My question is if there is a possibility to check if the CREATED_ON field includes a value which is parsable to DATETIME or not when getting all entries? Even a foreach loop does not help because every entry is trying to be parsed in the given class before.

EDIT:

Yes the field is straight mapped to DATETIME

```
builder.Entity<FileInfos>().
    Property(i => i.CreatedOn).
    HasColumnName("CREATED_ON");
```

In the FileInfos class:

```
public DateTime CreatedOn
{
    get { return CreatedOnInternal.ToUniversalTime(); }
    set { CreatedOnInternal = value.ToUniversalTime(); }
}
```

Comment: The exception suggests that you mapped the database column straight to a datetime property. Can we see the relevant parts of the involved class and mapping?

Comment: Well, that's something EF can't handle. You have to map string to string. Inside your entity you can try to parse the string value to an unmapped DateTime property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateTime.TryParse(input, **out** variable to output to if correct)

Example:

```
    string input = "2000-02-02";
    DateTime dateTime;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(input, out dateTime))
    {
        //only print if the parsing was successful
        Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
    }
```